# Modulo division

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y_{n}$ be the sum of n-independent rolls of a fair die. I am having a bit of trouble calculating the probability that that the sum of n-independent rolls are divisible by 7.

I do understand that P(1 roll divisible by 7) = 0
P(2 rolls divisible by 7) = $P(X=7) = 6/36$
P(3 rolls divisible by 7) =$ P(X=7) + P(X=14) = 31/216$, I think.
I am trying to figure for 4, 5, and 6 rolls of the die, does anyone have a general solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I am just trying to come up with an algorithm to calculate if the sum of n rolls of a die is divisible by 7.

Comment: Do you know what a Markov chain is?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am trying to find the probabilities for the 7 state transition matrix.

Comment: sum of coefficients of $x^{7n}$ in $1+ (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^k$

Comment: I still feel like there is something basic there that I am missing. What exactly am I summing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simpler way to attack this would be to define a sequence $Y_n$ of random variables, where $Y_n$ is the remainder modulo $7$ of the sum of the first $n$ throws. Then define the generating series $Z_n = \sum_{i \in \mathbb Z / 7 \mathbb Z} P(Y_n=i) \,t^i$ in $R = \mathbb Z[t]/t^7-1$. It should be easy to convince yourself that:

1. $Z_0 = 1$,
2. $Z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{6}(t+t^2+\dots+t^6) Z_{n}$,

so that all we have to do is evaluate $q(t)^n$, where $q(t) = (t+\dots+t^6)/6 \pmod{t^7-1}$.

To do this, we now diagonalize $q$. For all primitive roots $\zeta \neq 1$, we have $q(\zeta) = -1/6$. For $t = 1$, we have $q(1) = 1$. This gives
$Z_n(1) = q(1)^n Z_0(1) = 1$ and $Z_n(\zeta) = q(\zeta)^n Z_0(\zeta) = (-1/6)^n$ for $\zeta \neq 1$.

We may finally interpolate $Z_n$: it takes the values $1$ on $1$ and $(-1/6)^n$ on all primitive roots $\zeta$. Since the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7 = 1 + \dots + t^6$ is the (unique) element of $R$ such that $\Phi_7(1) = 7$ and $\Phi_7(\zeta) = 0$ for  all other $\zeta$, we find that
$$ Z_n(t) = (-1/6)^n + \frac{1}{7} \left(1-(-1/6)^n\right) (1-\Phi_7(t)).$$

The solution to your problem is now
$$ P(Y_n = 0) = Z_n(0) = \frac{1}{7} + \frac{6}{7} \left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)^n.$$
We check by hand that it has the correct first values $Z_n(0) = 1$, $Z_n(1) = 0$, $Z_n(2) = 1/6$...

*Oh, of course, you can also do this with matrices instead of generating polynomials. But polynomials are simpler, and I did not want to write $7\times 7$ matrices.*

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_{n}$ denote the event that $7$ divides $Y_{n}$.

Then:

$$P\left(E_{n}\right)=P\left(E_{n}\mid E_{n-1}\right)P\left(E_{n-1}\right)+P\left(E_{n}\mid E_{n-1}^{c}\right)P\left(E_{n-1}^{c}\right)=$$$$0P\left(E_{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(1-P\left(E_{n-1}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{6}\left(1-P\left(E_{n-1}\right)\right)$$